# Array with Commands

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files which I would like to move to other destinations. Issues:

1. Destination is different
2. Errors can occur, e.g. File does already exist in Destination.

If so, I would like to delete the existing file (e.g. `$StartM\C\A.Lnk`)

How can I do this with a list / foreach or other possibility?

```
Move-Item -Path "$StartM\C\A.Lnk" -Destination "$StartM\Maintenance"
Move-Item -Path "$StartM\C\B.Lnk" -Destination "$StartM"
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of dealing with a situation like that is to define a mapping between sources and destinations:

```
$shortcuts = @{
    "$StartM\C\A.Lnk" = "$StartM\Maintenance"
    "$StartM\C\B.Lnk" = "$StartM"
}
```

and then process that mapping like this:

```
foreach ($src in $shortcuts.Keys) {
    Remove-Item $shortcuts[$src] -Force -EA SiltenlyContinue
    Move-Item $src -Destination $shortcuts[$src]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar. Please see my answer and issues below: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007839/12403339

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ansgar. I got some issues:

**1. Remove-Item:** 
The Argument can not be bound with the Parameter "Path", because it is an empty string.

- CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

**2. Move-Item:** 
No position parameter was found, which accept the argument "\Maintenance"

May be there is a missunderstanding. Source should be deleted if exists in Destination. E.g.: "$StartM\C\A.Lnk" = "$StartM\Maintenance". 
**Goal**: "$StartM\C\A.Lnk" should be deleted if "A.Lnk" exists in "$StartM\Maintenance\A.Lnk".

- Move-Item $src = $shortcuts[$src]
- CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId: PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

**3. ErrorAction**
Remove-Item: The Parameter "ErrorAction" can not be bound. Type "SiltenlyContinue" can not be converted in type "System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference" ... 
I just changed "-EA" ... -Force -EA SilentlyContinuefrom to "-Error Action". This type of Error has gone.

**4. Double keys**
If there are some constelations in the array like this:
"$StartM\C\B.Lnk" & "$End\C\B.Lnk" I got an error that double keys are not allowed in Hashliterals.

- CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collections.Hashtable:Hashtable) [], RuntimeException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : DuplicateKeyInHashLiteral